# nautilus elementary coverflow not working

Tags: nautilus-elementary

I installed it and press F4 and nothing happens. Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will definitely help. Worked for me.

[How to fix the blank screen on clutterview problem on ubuntu 10.10 maverick meerkat](http://open-help.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-fix-blank-screen-on-clutterview.html)

And here's the contents of the link in case it goes down:

> Couple of days ago I installed “Nautilus Elementary” on my Ubuntu maverick meerkat. Strangely I was not able to enable clutterview. When I pressed F4 it just showed a black blank screen and that was real annoying. A few considerable search on google showed me the way to fix this, a comment on webupd8.com.
>
> The Fix:
>
> The problem is linked to a vblank issue which occurres in combination with Intel GFX cards and clutter services. To fix this edit /etc/environment by issuing the command:
>
> `sudo gedit /etc/environment`
>
> and add the line
>
> `export CLUTTER_VBLANK=none`
>
> Save it and reboot your system. Clutterview should work like a charm now.

Via gokul at [theopenhelp.com](http://theopenhelp.com/)

Comment: You're my hero.