# Clutterflow not working on Nautilus Elementary

Tags: 11.04, nautilus-elementary, clutterflow

I tried what is written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8999/nautilus-elementary-coverflow-not-working) but i couldn't make clutterflow work. Are there any packages needed for it to run?

Comment: Could you expand on what you've done. EG, what ppa did you install elementary from? Any issues? Video card? Platform? (laptop? desktop?) Did you install gloobus-preview as well? The more you can provide, the better for someone to zoom in on your issue. I did a clean Natty install the day after release, installed elementary (with a hack to install gloobus-preview), and everything works as advertised here.

Comment: I installed elementary from their "official" ppa - the one shown on omgubuntu. I have no other issue with it. I use an nvidia 330m on a fujitsu laptop and i'm on 11.04. I don't have gloobus-preview installed because its installation was stopped and now it won't let me install it, saying i have kept broken packages (that don't appear on the "broken packages" list on synaptic) (could this have affected clutterflow as well?)

Comment: Believe clutter-flow and gloobus-preview are separate entities. Don't know if it will help but I can tell you how to get GP installed:

Comment: Opps. Sorry, hit `<enter>` by mistook...

Comment: 1. install libpoppler7 if not already installed; it won't muck up your existing libpopper12? install.
2. aptitude purge gloobus-preview
3. reinstall aptitude install gloobus-preview
4. let it fail; when it does, note the last line that refs where the failed file is located `/var/lib/something/or/another`
5. Open the failed *postinstall file in vi and comment out the section that refs libpixbuf or pixbuf (sorry, doing this from memory). It the only section "open". Comment it all out.
6. run `aptitude install -f`
7. it should install without incident
Might help your clutter ;-)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer - it worked solved the gloobus-preview problem. It also let me reinstall nautilus, which wasn't possible while gloobus had a bad mood. Unfortunately it didn't solve the clutter issue though. Can you tell me what clutter related packages you have installed?

Comment: yes. it does not solve clutter window problem. i still dont have clutter flow in nautilus elementary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus-elementary/+bug/753283) to solve my issue.

For those too bored to read the , really small, page here is what you need to do :

First , as Heiko Schulze wrote :

> Solution:
>   Press ALT + F2, enter: gconf-editor and then navigate to apps > nautilus > preferences and enable 'show_clutter'.
>   Restart Nautilus (nautilus -q). Ready for the next issue...

Before you press the nautilus -q command you should, as ammonkey wrote , make the "clutter-test" part found in apps>nautilus>preferences of the gconf-editor to 0 as well